# Regex to match string starting and between specific word

Tags: regex

I have this string :

`<a href="/article/aujourd-hui-moment-calin-avec-mon-copain-attache-et-a-4-pattes-il-finis-en-moi-et-recoit-u_267211.html">
Aujourd&#x2019;hui, moment &#xE0; la fois c&#xE2;lin et torride avec mon copain. On se fait un petit d&#xE9;lire BDSM et, me retrouvant &#xE0; 4 pattes, il m&apos;attache. Apr&#xE8;s cette session o&#xF9; on en a fini, il re&#xE7;oit un appel urgent et part. En me laissant comme &#xE7;a. VDM
</a>`

and I would like to get this one :

`Aujourd&#x2019;hui, moment &#xE0; la fois c&#xE2;lin et torride avec mon copain. On se fait un petit d&#xE9;lire BDSM et, me retrouvant &#xE0; 4 pattes, il m&apos;attache. Apr&#xE8;s cette session o&#xF9; on en a fini, il re&#xE7;oit un appel urgent et part. En me laissant comme &#xE7;a. VDM`

I have made research and succeed with this regular expression

> [^>]+(?=\<)

the problem is that I have other String like that :

```
<a href="/aleatoire">Al&#xE9;atoire <span class="rub_icon icon-dice"></span></a>
```

with this String and the Regex I get `Al&#xE9;atoire` and that **is not good**.

So I want to improve the Regex to **GET ONLY** the Entire sentence that **BEGINS** with `Aujourd&#x2019;hui`
Can someone have a solution ? I am not use to Regex.

Comment: Equation of the day: `regex + HTML = EVIL!!!`

Comment: Regex has no language. I just want to parse a String that is formatted as HTML but it's basically jsute words and symbol.

Comment: Did you add linebreaks to improve readability, or are there 7 lines of input? Or 3? Or doesn't it matter? With a little phantasy, you can generate zillions of regexes which match in a single, specific case.

Answer (score 0):

so, based on your explanation:

```
>\s?(Aujourd&#x2019;hui.*?)\s?<

>< specifies that content is between brackets (outside of html)

\s? specifies that there may be, but doesnt have to be whitespace
```

without:

```
 <a>string</a>
```

with:

```
 <a>
   string
 </a>

 Aujourd&#x2019;hui specifies match has to start with this word

 .*? specifies optional additional characters in string
```

i hope the order is obvious.

> edit: to avoid confusion, we are talking about `_match` functions, with
>   full regex being `/>\s?(Aujourd&#x2019;hui.*?)\s?</g`.
>
> https://regex101.com/r/F0bPWN/2

Comment: No, I want the output specified. with a basic Regex, without html or script code only regex. And to prove that the regex works if we test it on the last string, it has to return nothing

Comment: please, could you specife where and how is the regex being used if not as part of javascript, jquery or php? also, you want it to retyrn first occurance of content between html? or anythign beginning with specified word? or? i see that you need to return something in 1st case, the nnothing in 2nd case. but to properly specify what are differences between these cases, i need to see the bigger picture.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/F0bPWN/1 take this link as workspace. No language, only regex. I need only the line that start with `Aujourd&#x2019;hui`

Comment: *its not clear in your question, but lets say that you: what: read entire html file 2. want to extract all substrings that are inside >< and start with specific word 3. you do so in javascript or php? using which functions? inside html <input> with attribute pattern="" ? any application? if you specify these properly, its going to be easy to help you.

Comment: if you need only that link, you can manually copy it. the thing is, you need some application or script to process it instead right? then specify what that is.

Comment: No application, no attribute, no nothing. I don't know how to say but it's only regex. You get what I want to do but... there is no programming language behind it. Go on this link please you will understand : [RegexTester](http://regex101.com/r/F0bPWN/1) This link is here to CREATE and TEST regex.

Comment: ok, so in the link, i can see php: preg_match_all() and similar functions in other languages. the thing is, you can go with _match, or _replace, and looking at link you sent, you practically specified method how regex is used.

Comment: I give up. I can't explain more. TY by the way

Comment: >\n?(Aujourd&#x2019;hui.*?)\n?<   but note its used for match and full regex is: />\n?(Aujourd&#x2019;hui.*?)\n?</g. also it may not work properly if you introduce additional input that fits parameters.

Comment: sorry, a change from \n? to \s? will allow any whitespace, even tabs and spaces etc. more proper for html

Answer (score 0):

In Sed, to only print lines not starting with a tag, you can use:

```
sed -n '/^[^<].*$/p' fr.html 
Aujourd&#x2019;hui, moment &#xE0; la fois c&#xE2;lin et torride avec mon copain. On se fait un petit d&#xE9;lire BDSM et, me retrouvant &#xE0; 4 pattes, il m&apos;attache. Apr&#xE8;s cette session o&#xF9; on en a fini, il re&#xE7;oit un appel urgent et part. En me laissant comme &#xE7;a. VDM
```

Or you could do the opposite thing twice, delete lines starting with a tag:

```
sed  '/^<.*$/d' fr.html 
Aujourd&#x2019;hui, moment &#xE0; la fois c&#xE2;lin et torride avec mon copain. On se fait un petit d&#xE9;lire BDSM et, me retrouvant &#xE0; 4 pattes, il m&apos;attache. Apr&#xE8;s cette session o&#xF9; on en a fini, il re&#xE7;oit un appel urgent et part. En me laissant comme &#xE7;a. VDM
```